# C++ Pass Member to Main () as variable

Tags: c++, object

I found this example online. I know it is possible to get the sum of the array in the `PutData()` member function, but how can you pass this to the `main()` to use as a variable properly? I understand it is probably best to have a member function for sum, but for simplicity, I think you should understand what I am trying to do.

I have been successfully at calling the members in main, but how can I assign it to a new variable to use in `main()`?

Thank you in advance

```
#include<iostream>


class Employee
{
    int Id;
    char Name[25];
    int Age;
    long Salary;

    public:
    void GetData()      
    {
        cout<<"\n\tEnter Employee Id : ";
        cin>>Id;

        cout<<"\n\tEnter Employee Name : ";
        cin>>Name;

        cout<<"\n\tEnter Employee Age : ";
        cin>>Age;

        cout<<"\n\tEnter Employee Salary : ";
        cin>>Salary;
    }

    void PutData()           
    {
        sum = id + age;
        cout<<"\n"<<Id<<"\t"<<Name<<"\t"<<Age<<"\t"<<Salary;
        cout << sum;
    }    
};


int main()
{
    int i;

    Employee E[3];           

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter details of "<<i+1<<" Employee";
        E[i].GetData();
    }

    cout<<"\nDetails of Employees";
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    E[i].PutData();
}
```

EDIT: Thank you everyone for the help!
I was able to get the sum of every employee individually with help from the comments.

I created a different member

```
int GetSum()
{
return Age + Id;
}
```

and my main is:

```
int sum1 = P[0].GetSum();
cout << "\nSUM OF TEAM 1:  " << sum1;

int sum2 = P[1].GetSum();
cout << "\nSUM OF TEAM 2:  " << sum2;
```

Comment: You want to return the sum instead of PutData() being void. So simply just change the type to int and it will be a single line "return id + age"

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. You've simply repeated the tag information. Your title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will be useful to future users here who are scanning a list of search results for a solution. While you're making that edit, you can more clearly describe the problem you're having and ask a more specific question so that we can try to help.

Comment: Why not simply write a `getSum()` member function that returns the sum of `id + age`?

Comment: @Girspoon How would this be called in the main out side of the array?

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Hello, in my program I did create a sum() member, but when called in main, I couldn't do anything except what was within the member function if that makes sense. I want to assign the value of this "sum" from my class, assign it to a completely new variable and work with it inside my main without needing the class anymore

Comment: I would do as @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica suggests and rename it but the idea is the same. In main you can say int sum =  E[0].GetSum(); to get the sum of the first employee in the array

Comment: @Girspoon Okay, I believe I have been calling the function wrong in main. I had done Teams E; and E.GetSum(); to call and of course, that is not going to work. I will try this way. Thank you both!

Comment: Why not write in `class Employee` a function `int getSum() { return age + id; }` and then in `main()` just call `int sum = getSum();` (after you have created an instance of the class and initialized `age` and `id` in the constructor or set them explicitly)?

Answer (score 0):

By default, classes' members are `private`, that is you can't access an instance's members directly. So you have two options.

#### Add a member function

So as suggested by others in the comments, you can add a class function, which returns the sum of the two members.

```cpp
class Employee
{
    int Id;
    char Name[25];
    int Age;
    long Salary;

    public:
    void GetData();
    void PutData();
    int  GetSum();
}

int Employee::GetSum(){
    return Id + Age;
}
```

Then in `main()` you call the function to get the result.

```cpp
int main() {
    Employee E;
    E.GetData();
    std::cout << "Sum is " << E.GetSum() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Make the fields `public`

Class members which are `public` *can* be accessed directly. Warning though, this is not good practice when it comes to *encapsulation* in object oriented programming.

```cpp
class Employee
{
    char Name[25];
    long Salary;

    public:
    int Id;
    int Age;
    void GetData();
    void PutData();
}
```

Then you can get them using the `.` operator within `main()`:

```cpp
int main() {
    Employee E;
    E.GetData();
    std::cout << "Sum is " << E.id + E.age << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```